# Vue mixing library and app builds, how to handle Vue instance?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

When we started with Vue, we've built all our components as libraries and included Vue runtime in the HTML head and had a stupid root instance around the whole body, so we could just use our custom tags wherever we wanted. To optimize the build process and general code cleanup, I now wanted to change this to an app build, which is the default for VueCLI. The problem is, we have two large third party components: [VueGoodTable](https://github.com/xaksis/vue-good-table) and [tiptap (an RTE)](https://tiptap.dev/), the latter with some customization. So to keep the vendor-chunk small, I wanted to keep these two as two separate libraries as they are not needed everywhere.

Now the problem is, that these libraries need a global Vue, so they can register themselves also globally. For VGT, we have a small wrapper (also because we use TypeScript):

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import 'vue-good-table/dist/vue-good-table.css';
import '@/assets/vue-good-table-custom.css';
const VueGoodTable: any = {
    'vue-good-table': require('vue-good-table').VueGoodTable,
};
Vue.component('VueGoodTable', VueGoodTable);
```

We also have some global filters so I thought I can just expose Vue there as well:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

import './assets/global.css';

Vue.filter('formatDate', (dateStr: string) => {
    if (dateStr) {
        return dayjs(dateStr).format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm');
    }
});
Vue.filter('displayUser', (userObj: any) => {
    if (userObj) {
        if (userObj.firstName && userObj.lastName) {
            return userObj.firstName + ' ' + userObj.lastName;
        }
        return userObj.email;
    }
});

window.Vue = Vue;
```

For some reason this works on one page but not the others; `Cannot read property 'component' of undefined` where we do this: `Vue.component('VueGoodTable', VueGoodTable);`

Two questions:

1. Is this the correct way to expose Vue globally?
2. Is there a way to exclude Vue from the app build like it is for library builds? I found an option to include Vue in the library build, but not the other way round.

Any other suggestions on how to handle this are welcome as well.

EDIT:
I found out why it was not working, the vue.config.js was different for the one page that was working. But I'll keep the question open as I'd like to know "better" ways to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like exposing your libraries as a [Vue plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) might be a good fit. That way, you don't need a global Vue instance, but instead the Vue instance is passed into the library when it is installed.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin

Comment: And how would I add this plugin to the VueCLI build so it would be in a separate js file in the end? On first glance it looks like this would be added to the vendort-chunk as well as I need to reference it somewhere in my app component.